# Inverse image of an arbitrary Borel set $B \in \mathbb{R}$ under $f(x) = \min\{|x|, 1\}$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing, borel-sets

I am trying to go through some proofs and exercises about measure theory.

In particular, I have the following exercise to solve:

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x) = \min\{|x|, 1\}$. Show that the inverse image of an arbitrary Borel set $B \in \mathbb{R}$ is given by:
> $$ f^{-1}(B) = 
>      \begin{cases}
>        \{x: |x| \in B \cap [0,1)\} & \text{if $1 \notin B$}\\
>        \{x: |x| \in B \cap [0,1)\} \cup \{1\} & \text{if $1 \in B$}.
>      \end{cases} \tag{1}\label{eq:1}  $$

To show that Eq. $\eqref{eq:1}$ holds, we need to prove that the r.h.s. matches with $f^{-1}(B) = \{x: \min\{|x|,1 \} \in B\}$ (from the definition of inverse image).

This entails that $f^{-1}(B) = \{x: \{|x| \in B\}\text{ or }\{1 \in B\}\}$.

However, I am struggling showing that.

Can someone give me some help here?

Comment: That's not true: Take for example $B=[0,2]$, then $f^{-1}([0,2])=[0,1]$ according to (1), but according to the RHS of the last equation, $2\in f^{-1}(B)$, since $|2|=2\in B$. It's right if you put on the RHS $\{x\in[0,1]|\cdots\}$.

Comment: @Alessandro thanks for your comment. I see what you are saying. Is it correct, then, to say that it always holds $f^{-1}(B) = \{x: x \in [0,1]\}$? And can one directly infer it from $f^{−1}(B)=\{x: \min\{|x|,1\} \in B\}$?

Comment: No, because $\{x:x\in[0,1]\}$ is just $[0,1]$

Comment: In this case, there's a direct argument (by definition $x\in f^{-1}(B)$ if and only if $f(x)\in B$, but then either $f(x)=|x|$, or $1\leq |x|$ and $1\in B$). However, since you need to prove something like $A=B$ ($A,B$ sets), the general strategy would be to just assume $1\in B$ or $1\notin B$ and prove $f^{-1}(B)=B\cap[0,1)$ or $f^{-1}(B)=B\cap[0,1]$.